# How to return multiple values ​from a PHP array (PHP-XML)?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I need help extracting data from a **PHP** array, after which I need to create an **XML** tag.
I have a string as you can see below.
Sometimes there is one data, ie a picture, sometimes there are several pictures

```
[0]=> "https://test.com/1.jpg" 
[1]=> "https://test.com/2.jpg" 
[2]=> "https://test.com/3.jpg"
...
```

I created a php function, which works well with when it encounters a single image, however when it encounters multiple images it returns only the first element (image) in the array.

```
function Photo($Images) 
    {
    $br=count($Images);
    if ($br==1){ return "<photo><url>".$Images."</url><priority><![CDATA[1]]></priority></photo>"; }
    elseif ($br>1) 
        {
            $broj=count($Images);
            foreach ($Images as $value) 
            {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $broj; $i++) {
                }
                return "<photo><url>$value</url></photo>";
            }
        }
    }
```

I need the function to return an XML tag with the URL of the image and the ordinal number in the sequence, e.g.

```
<photo> <url> https://test.com/1.jpg </url> <priority> 1 </priority> </photo>
<photo> <url> https://test.com/2.jpg </url> <priority> 2 </priority> </photo>
etc
```

I have a problem with nested XML and with a return function in PHP.
In other words, I need the function to return all the elements of the array, not just the first one.

With echo, he shoots me everything and reports a bug.

I'm learning PHP and I need help

Thanks

Comment: Your `for` loop does nothing. And instead of `return`ing your result right away (this will stop the `foreach` loop) rather add your results to an array you can use later on.

Comment: It would be worth trying to use SimpleXML rather than trying to use strings to create the XML data.

Comment: maybe this simpleXML example helps you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml-in-php/ -> instead of directly returning as brombeer mentioned already, you can call the function itself again if you encounter nested structures

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you use the `return` keyword, which aborts the entire function, and ends the `for` loop early, only returning the first value in the array.

Instead, one option is to have a string that contains the current XML that you have, and keep adding onto it until the `for` loop completes. After the `for` loop, you can `return` that string.

```php
function Photo($Images) {
    $br = count($Images);
    if ($br == 1) {
        return "<photo><url>".$Images."</url><priority><![CDATA[1]]></priority></photo>";
    } elseif ($br > 1) {
        // Start off with an empty string
        $imagesString = "";
        foreach ($Images as $value) {
            // Append to the end of the string
            $imagesString .= "<photo><url>$value</url></photo>";
        }
        return $imagesString;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much.

Comment: @Vlada If this answer solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it when you can so it can be closed. Thanks